# Behavior of kernel density estimation

Tags: density-function, monte-carlo, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

Consider the random variable $X=YZ$, where $Y\sim\text{Normal}(0,1)$ and $Z\sim\text{log-Normal}(0,1)$ are independent. I wanted to assess the accuracy of kernel density estimates for the density function of $X$. To do so, I analyzed the error $\| f_X^M-f_X\|_\infty$, where $f_X$ is the exact density of $X$ and $f_X^M$ is the estimated density using $M$ realizations. I noticed the following unexpected behavior: the error decreases to $0$ as $M$ grows until a certain $M_0$, and for $M\geq M_0$ the error estabilizes and does not decrease anymore. Here you have an example of errors, for $M\in \{1000\times 2^j:j=0,\ldots,14\} $: $\{0.122676, 0.128692, 0.106668, 0.0966931, 0.0864821, 
0.0701135, 0.0588748, 0.0539388, 0.0605349, 0.0519725, 0.0530177, 
0.0518811, 0.0516745, 0.0520293, 0.0534252\}.$ As you see, the error stops at $0.05$ and even gets bigger as $M$ increases in the end. If I perform the same procedure again for different realizations, the same issue occurs. Is there any explanation for this behavior? Is this inherent and unavoidable for kernel density methods? Can this be solved just by selecting the correct bandwidth as $M$ increases?

Comment: What exactly is "unexpected" in here? In most cases, whatever you estimate the error will decrease with sample size and stabilize at "big enough" sample.

Comment: @Tim Why is there stabilization? I thought there was convergence as $M\rightarrow\infty$, so I would expect that the error decreases to $0$ as $M$ grows. Do you know any theory or other examples that justify such behavior?